# Mysql keeps restarting (but i'm not sure why)

Tags: mysql

I recently discovered the following error in a log

```
Oct 14 10:21:43 squire-labs kernel: [4186256.684193] init: mysql main process (16331) terminated with status 1
Oct 14 10:21:43 squire-labs kernel: [4186256.684215] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Oct 14 10:21:44 squire-labs kernel: [4186257.394474] type=1400 audit(1381738904.046:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=28201 comm="apparmor_parser"
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28254]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28257]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28257]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28257]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28257]: This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.29, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28269]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Oct 14 10:21:47 squire-labs /etc/mysql/debian-start[28274]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
```

This happens often (at least 4 times a minute). I'm really not sure what might be causing this issue. Mysql is running on a production server, with enough disk space and memory. Up until yesterday we've never had any problems.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need more detailed logging and monitoring of the logs when the problem actually happens. There's 5.5.32 version of this package, maybe try to upgrade to it. Chekout myslq logs, syslog and dmesg to see if there are any other problems that might cause mysql to stop.

Comment: I'm using version 5.5.32. The log above comes from syslog. There's nothing in mysql.err. I can't seem to get any more logging information. Dmesg doesn't have anything either.

Comment: what is that message  This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.29; Do you have 2 separate mysql instances running?

Comment: I think what happened is that the upgrade kept failing because of the mysql server crash (however the version was 5.5.32 when I checked it out).

Comment: make dump of the data and try it on different machine to see if it's from the data. Otherwise try to re-install mysql-server.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer and not as an edit of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that one of my tables in one of the dbs was corrupted. [This article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/07/04/recovering-innodb-table-corruption/) proved to be very useful.

In the end, I simply made a `mysqldump` of the database and restored the dump to a new database. That solved the problem.